# Dectecting spam on a chat room

Tags: c#, .net, spam-prevention

Say someone starts spamming a chat with random characters. How would I determine in **C#** if the string is just random characters or them legitimately talking?

1. I've removed a few words I don't want them to say.
2. I've removed links/emails from chat.
3. I've stopped them from sending messages too fast.
4. I've stopped them from saying the same thing multiple times in a row.

Number 4 is where the problem begins. Well the problem actually begins with me trying to filter a chat, but that's another discussion. 
They have now learned that it only checks if it's the same thing and now spam random characters.

*This is for a game that I only have control over the servers code.*

Comment: It wouldn't help: once you learn to detect random sequences of characters, they'll start constructing random sequences of English words, English sentences that almost make sense, or even excerpts from news sites that look legitimate even to humans. The arms race is on, a computer against a man cannot win it. You need human eyes to detect spam, CAPTCHA to minimize it, and good  banning policies to discourage further spam.

Comment: Unfortunately, having any sort of automatic system to detect spammage is going to be really difficult if the spammer is dedicated.  If you start checking for random characters, the next thing they'll do is append a bunch of random words pulled from a dictionary.  If you somehow manage to detect that, they'll start appending entire sentences pulled automatically from other websites.  Eventually you'll have to come up with some kind of huge context-sensitive heuristic like modern e-mail spam filters.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess I'll have to rely on a few moderators to clean up the chat then.

Comment: Don't see why this has to be closed. The question is well written (Except for the title, which I changed) and @dasblinkenlight and jeremy 's comments are as good as answers.

Comment: @gideon Although our comments aren't as good as answers because they do not explain how to detect random strings, only suggest that even a  correct answer would probably not help the OP, I think the question is a good one. I agree that this is a legitimate and interesting problem, and I do not think that this question should be closed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight exactly, because anyone who does have the same problem will find your comments helpful while coming toward a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any event, you can only go so far before your efforts have little to no return vs effort of coding.  What would probably be better is to to something like how stack overflow or world of warcraft work, where the users have more control.  In WOW a player can click on someone's name in the chat box and simply *report as spam(mer)*.

It wouldn't be to hard to say if some percentage of people who can see the message, report it, then most likely that person is spamming.  You can then auto-decide or mark it for review, or however you want to deal with it.  Since your problem is detecting spam, if users are going to see it (which they are) why not allow them to help alleviate the problem.

I think being honest with users and saying, we have a problem, we need your help, and making it easy for users to help shows a level of maturity.